# Installing Ubuntu next to Windows XP

Tags: ubuntu

I have iso image for Ubuntu 11.0.4 on a CD. My OS is windows XP. I have 3 partions c, E and F. Windows is installed on C, and F has data. E is empty drive. Now, after I start installation , I choose the third option. Then click forward and I am shown three figures --

```
/dev/sda1 52427(total)/50931(used)

/dev/sda5 52427(total)/3221(used)
```

-- surprised, since it should be empty. I had used wubi to install earlier but have uninstalled.

```
/dev/sda5 215206(total)/37545(used)
```

Now, it means I need to choose sda5. Now how should I go about creating 3 partions for /(root), /home and /swap. Click edit partion and give size for each of them?

Answer (score 0):

/dev/sda1 means the first primary partition on the first SATA-controller (it would be sdb1 on the second controller and hda1 on an IDE-controller). You can only have 4 primary partitions, so the first logical partition is sda5. Look under "Control Panel - Administrative Tools - Computer Management" in windows to see what partitions you have and if they are empty.
You don't have to install Ubuntu on 3 seperate partitions, this is a recommendation. If your computer has kind of up to date hardware you don't need a swap partition either...

Answer (score 0):

For performance and dependency reasons, regular installations are preferred over Wubi installations. The Wubi installation will be installed over a NTFS partition.

The drive letters do not have to match the partition in order. The second partition could be E as well, you'd better check the size to identify the partition. After identified the E drive, remove it and boot from a LiveCD / LiveUSB to do a regular installation.

Consider this partition scheme:

- `/` (root): 30GB
- swap: depends on your usage, do not over twice your RAM
- `/home`: everything that's left. Documents and settings will go in here.